# How to remove in PHP all HTML <sup> and some CSS Classes from a PHP variable?

Tags: php

I have a PHP variable named `$matches[0]` which contains a HTML Code.

So, I want to know if is there a way to remove in PHP any from `$matches[0]` variable these **HTML Tags** and/or **CSS class**:

- `<sup>...</sup>` (*HTML Tags*) ???
- `class="navigation-only"` (*CSS Class*) ???
- `class="noprint wikidata-linkback"` (*CSS Class*) ???

If so, how to do to remove all HTML `<sup>` and `navigation-only` and `noprint wikidata-linkback` CSS Classes ???

Because it will very help me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: Xpath query on a DOMNode